# How to ignore ssl in react native using axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I am using axios for the server call . I am trying to ignore the ssl for the client side.

I have followed the issue mentioned in axios github
but there is no https in react native.If anyone has faced this issue already can help me to solve this.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});
```

Issue link: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535

Comment: Maybe this will not help you but while you are testing you can use http protocol. In production I would anyway suggest you to use CA-signed certificates for example from letsencrypt.org (it is free). Then you're getting better security and the problem with self-signed certificates will be gone.